# Return multiple validation failures from a single Custom() rule?

Tags: fluentvalidation

Using FluentValidation and a `Custom()` rule, I want to be able to validate a collection of child objects, and return a `ValidationFailure` for each child object that is invalid.

I can't use a collection validator because the child object doesn't contain the right information to execute the rule - it must run in the context of the parent.

However the `Custom()` API limits me to returning a single `ValidationFailure` or nothing at all.

Is there a pattern I can use that allows a single rule to generate multiple errors?

Comment: i have too reached to this point . is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution - use AddRule() with a DelegateValidator.

```
public MyValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        AddRule(new DelegateValidator<MyClass>(MyRule));
    }

    private IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> MyRule(
        MyClass instance, 
        ValidationContext<MyClass> context)
    {
        var result = new List<ValidationFailure>();

        // add as many failures to the list as you want:
        var message = "This is not a valid message";
        result.Add(new ValidationFailure(nameof(MyClass.SomeProperty), message));

        return result;
    }
}
```